# What is the main purpose of NodeJS internal HTTP Web Server?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I'm currently learning NodeJS and pretty excited about it.
But here is one thing that I am unsure and need help about.

As we know that NodeJS has its own internal http web server and we can simply create using `http.createServer()` method.

My questions are:

1. Is the internal http web server that NodeJS has, meant to replace similar http web server like Apache or Nginx?
2. If I need to create enterprise-scale application, does NodeJS internal web service capable of doing this? Or do I need to still use Apache/Nginx?

Please help. Thank you.
Adrian

Comment: yes it is to replace Apache and likes, however each solution has it's own strengths and drawbacks.

Comment: I'm not sure about enterprise-scale apps, but Node.js is very good for  creating real-time apps (e.g. chats). If you are interested with it you will probably find [socket.io](http://socket.io/) useful.

Comment: Thanks all, after reading your answers and comments, I finally decided to use **NodeJS http web server ONLY** since it has passed some stressed test in every way I can think of. Another thing in my consideration is that this web server will serve static files only. So help me God I'm making the correct decision.

Answer (score 0):

1. node.js does not require a web server the likes of Apache or nginx, it is its own web server.
2. Walmart has used node for, in their words, "[end-to-end javascript](http://venturebeat.com/2012/01/24/why-walmart-is-using-node-js/)"... that is certainly enterprise-scale, though they don't explicitly say they're relying on `http.createServer`, end-to-end javascript would eliminate Apache or nginx and I doubt they've developed some exotic solution (though socket.io is a possibility)... generally speaking if you're using node on the web, you're using the built in web server in at least some capacity.

There perhaps is some benefit to using nginx as a reverse-proxy/static file server on the front end.  If I were designing my "perfect system" I'd probably do that, but I'd still be passing back requests to the built in web server in node.

Comment: If you check the response headers when you connect to www.walmart.com one of the fields is "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1". And Coyote is part of [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Coyote) which is made to serve Java servlets.

Comment: I do believe that the "end-to-end javascript" they are referring to is an app, not their full website, but it was deployed over Black Friday and experienced extreme loads, so the scale is not in question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Apache or Nginx with node.js, but in practice, its probably a good idea.

Basically, Apache would sit in front of your node.js, and relay requests to and from your node app, using something like mod_rewrite.

The node http server module is great for firing up quick applications, but if you need things like SSL, complex mod_rewrites, directory security, detailed logs etc (ie all the stuff you would need in a commercial application), you need (or at least, its easier) to use Apache or Nginx in front of node.

Comment: Having used both Apache and node, I disagree that it's easier to do those things in Apache.  Specifically, SSL is very easy in node, mod_rewrite isn't really relevant in node (or at least, the way to accomplish the same goal is intuitive and straight forward, rather than the mess I always run into in Apache)...  nginx may be another matter.  I would recommend pursuing any other setup other than Apache+node, it's not that it's bad per-se, but there are better choices out there.